# Surround images based on selection made

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker show-html">
    <option data-img-src="http://placehold.it/125x200" value="1">SportField 1</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placehold.it/125x200" value="2">SportField 2</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placehold.it/125x200" value="3">SportField 3</option>
    <option data-img-src="http://placehold.it/125x200" value="4">SportField 4</option>
</select>
```

And then using [Image Picker Plugin](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) I wrote this piece of code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("select").imagepicker({
            show_label: true,
            changed: function() {
            },
            clicked: function() {
            },
            selected: function() {
                console.log(this.attr('value'));
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

What I need here and need some help from community is allow just some certain of choices. Right now the only choices allowed are:

- SportField1-SportField2
- SportField3-SportField4
- SportField1-SportField2-SportField3-SportField4

What this means? When I pick the `SportField1` I can select `SportField2` meaning adjacent images but if you can see the latest allowed choice is the fourth `SportField`. How I can achieve this?

**EDIT**

Based on @Ruud suggestions I made the following changes, the HTML code is this one:

```
<select name="choice" id="choice">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
    <option value="5">AB</option>
    <option value="6">CD</option>
    <option value="7">ABCD</option>
</select>

<img src="http://placehold.it/125x200" data-id="A">
<img src="http://placehold.it/125x200" data-id="B">
<img src="http://placehold.it/125x200" data-id="C">
<img src="http://placehold.it/125x200" data-id="D">

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('choice').change(function() {

        });
    });
</script>
```

Now to explain a bit:

- if I pick choice A in select then image with `data-id=1` should get a line (this can be done by CSS)
- if I pick choice B in select then image with `data-id=2` should get a line (this can be done by CSS)
- if I pick choice C in select then image with `data-id=3` should get a line (this can be done by CSS)
- if I pick choice D in select then image with `data-id=4` should get a line (this can be done by CSS)
- if I pick choice AB in select then image with `data-id=1` and image with `data-id=2` should get a line (this can be done by CSS)
- if I pick choice CD in select then image with `data-id=3` and image with `data-id=3` should get a line (this can be done by CSS)
- if I pick choice ABCD in select then all images should get a line (this can be done by CSS)

How I can achieve this on `SELECT` change?

Comment: What a confusing user experience: once you selected picture 1, you are not allowed to select picture 3, unless it is done in combination with 2 and 4. My first thought would be to redesign the UI. For example, create a *collage*-like picture for each acceptable combination of pictures. Let the user select from there, then map the selected collage to the actual picture collection. How about some details about your use case? Also, how many pictures are there, and how many combinations?

Comment: @Ruud see my edit, maybe this help a bit to understand and help me to figure out how to get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function checks whether a particular image belongs in the current selection.
It does require you to use the picture IDs (e.g. ABCD) in the option's value; this seemed more logical to me than the 'magic numbers' 1-7.

```
function isSelected(selector, image) {
    return selector.find(':selected').text().indexOf(image.data('id')) >= 0;
};
```

It wasn't clear to me what you meant by "image should get a line", so I just made a simple demo that applies a CSS class to the selected images.
Please note I added the hash in `$('#choice')`; choice is an id, not a tag name.

```
$(function() {
    $('#choice').change(function() {
        var choice = $(this);   // = $('#choice');
        var allImages = $('img');
        var selectedImages = allImages.filter(function() { return isSelected(choice, $(this)); });

        allImages.removeClass('myprecious');
        selectedImages.addClass('myprecious');
    });
});
```

FYC, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UrKBZ/

Comment: I made a solution by myself but was ugly compared to yours, thanks